# Concatenating 1D arrays into 2D arrays with several 1D array columns

Tags: arrays, matlab, 2d

I have 3 Matlab 1 coloumn arrays and I want to turn them into one 3 column array. How can I do this?

For example.

```
 A1 =     A2=    A3=

| 1 |   | 4 |   | 7 | 
| 2 |   | 5 |   | 8 |
| 3 |   | 6 |   | 9 |
```

I want the output to be:

```
Output = 

| 1 4 7 |
| 2 5 8 |
| 3 6 9 |
```

Thank you!

Found the answer, and it was very simple:

```
Output = [A1 A2 A3]
```

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

```
B = horzcat(A1, horzcat(A2,A3))
```